# Nodebb how to use mongodb api

Tags: mongodb, nodebb

I got in trouble.Would someone like to tell me how write sql(mongondb + collections) in Nodebb.

```
var schoolnumber = req.session[cas.session_name];
    db.getObjectField('schoolnumber:' + schoolnumber, 'uid', function(err, ans) {
        console.log(1);
        if (err) {
            console.log('err');
        }else {
            console.log(ans)
            if (ans == null) {
                // res.redirect(nconf.get('relative_path') + '/register');
            }else {
                res.send( '<html><body>Hello!' + '</body></html>' );
            }
        }
    });
```

but i got this

```
1
null
```

I want to know how to 'select' (like mysql) data in NodeBB(mongodb) through a field (like 'schoolnumber')

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but [does this works for you](https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB/wiki/Database-Structure)?

```
db.objects.find({_key:"users:postcount"}, {_id: 0}).sort({score: -1}).pretty()


{ "_key" : "users:postcount", "value" : "2", "score" : 4121 }
{ "_key" : "users:postcount", "value" : "970", "score" : 2749 }
{ "_key" : "users:postcount", "value" : "3", "score" : 2190 }
{ "_key" : "users:postcount", "value" : "1", "score" : 1707 }
{ "_key" : "users:postcount", "value" : "598", "score" : 769 }
{ "_key" : "users:postcount", "value" : "11", "score" : 733 }
{ "_key" : "users:postcount", "value" : "477", "score" : 546 }
{ "_key" : "users:postcount", "value" : "587", "score" : 504 }
{ "_key" : "users:postcount", "value" : "747", "score" : 467 }
{ "_key" : "users:postcount", "value" : "302", "score" : 449 }
```

Comment: I want to use NodeBB api, but this seems to be command line format， Thank you

Comment: another question, Do you know where can i find Nodebb database api manual

Comment: @wanlipeng Can't find an API manual, however there seems to be a [forum for that](https://community.nodebb.org/)